# Join two SQL tables for %like% search.

Tags: php, html, sql, select

How would I be able to select from two tables. And searching both of them with the same 'like'  statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from user,info where name like '%$q%',title like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 10";
```

So I can get the data in `id` order together.

Comment: where name like '%$q%' and title like '%$q%'.Try this

Comment: I get this: "Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous"

Comment: This means that both tables have columns named "id". You should specify the table. Like `ORDER BY users.id`

Comment: That selects from just one table.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * from user JOIN info on user.id=info.id where name like '%$q%',title like '%$q%' order by user.id LIMIT 10";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should "connect" the two tables in some way. Specify the condition under which the rows will merge. Like **`user`.`id` = `info`.`userID`**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user`, `info` WHERE `user`.`id` = `info`.`userID` 
AND `name` LIKE '%$q%' AND `title` LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY `user`.`id` LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help u .

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User AS U INNER  JOIN Info AS I ON U.ID = I.ID WHERE Name LIKE '%$q%' AND title LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY U.ID LIMIT 10";
```

Please check above query . And if u dont want limit means u can use

//Oreder By **Ascending**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User AS U INNER  JOIN Info AS I ON U.ID = I.ID WHERE Name LIKE '%$q%' AND title LIKE '%$q%' order by id ASC";
```

//Order By **DESCENDING**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User AS U INNER  JOIN Info AS I ON U.ID = I.ID WHERE Name LIKE '%$q%' AND title LIKE '%$q%' order by id DESC";
```

Cheers...!!!